# How do I develop Custom search engine

Tags: search, search-engine

Here is what I want to do. I want to search in article. With text string "XXXX" and then a number in the same line "22663" and the search result would be listed according to ascending order of the "22663" that it has found.

For example I want to search "highest year" human lived ever. So there should be a number in the same line or near the line. And I want the results would be based on ascending order of the year.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about  Google's Custom Search API (or Web Search API) to search for keyword, then saving the first couple thousand results, and then searching through each file with the above process.